# Syntax error on tokens, AnnotationName expected instead in recyclerview - Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am getting this error "Syntax error on tokens, AnnotationName expected instead".Can anyone resolve it.-- Android

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(products.this){
                mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                      super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                      totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                      lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

                      if (!isLoading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {

                        if(totalItemCount!=array1.size()-1){
                          if (mOnLoadMoreListener != null) {
                              mOnLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                          }
                          isLoading = true;
                       }
                      }
                  }
              });
            }
            });
```

I m getting the error on line 2 i.e.
  mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
 mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()){
         // what ever you want to do here is only for LinearLayoutManager methods
    });

    mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            // implement your scrolled code here
        }
    });
```

Comment: Now, getting error -The method getActivity() is undefined for the type new Runnable(){}